# Calculating fields in jquery based on select in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to make a small app for tracking bets with Ruby and I have a small form, where I enter all kind of data (date, match and so on). The most important part of the form are two text fields the "stake" and the "odd". I figured out an easy jQuery code that calculates the "potential payout" right when I enter the stake and odd data and it goes like that:

```
$(function() {
  $("#stake, #odd").keyup(function() {
    var p = $("#stake").val();
    var q = $("#odd").val();

    $("#potential_payout").val(q * p);
  });
});
```

Now I would like to add a dropdown where I can select if the bet was successful by selecting "Yes" or "No" and at the same time if the bet was won make another calculation for:

profit = (potential_payout - stake) that would also be calculated live in the #profit text field.

I searched for a solution but didn't find something similar to my problem (but probably it's an easy thing). I was looking at how to set some global variables but couldn't figure it out as I'm a total noob in all this javascript, jquery, ajax.... If needed I can post the from html but I think it's quite straightforward.

I'll appreciate any advice.

Comment: Use .change on the drop down as you are using .keyup. The code is similar to what you have already done.

Comment: I did use the .change and even tried again with the code Gary posted below, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the majority of the code already.  Just need to perform the calculations.  I also went ahead and cached the selectors.

```
$(function() {

  var $stake = $('#stake');
      $odd = $('#odd'),
      $won = $('#won'),
      $payout = $('#potential_payout'),
      $profit = $('#profit');

  $stake.on('keyup', calculate);
  $odd.on('keyup', calculate);
  $won.on('change', calculate);

  function calculate() {
    var stake = $stake.val(),
       odd = $odd.val(),
       won = $won.val();
    $payout.val( stake * odd);
    if (won.toLowerCase() === "yes") {
      $profit.val( (stake*odd) - stake );
    }
  } 
});
```

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for your input. But somehow the profit field doesn't change when I select "Yes" in the dropdown. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the dropdown code, but it shouldn't

Comment: I've checked the code in the firebug console and the problem seems to be: TypeError: won is undefined 
if (won.toLowerCase() === "yes") {

Answer (score 0):

I played around today and I edited the ruby code for the dropdown to

```
<%= f.select :win, [['Yes','yes'],['No','no']], {include_blank: true, :onchange => "calculate()"}, :id =>"won" %>
```

from

```
<%= f.select :win, [['Yes','yes'],['No','no']], include_blank: true, :id =>"won" %>
```

and now it works. Thanks for your help!